# lead capture apps

Tags: looking-for-a-script, marketing

I'd like to build a lead capture website, where a visitor is required to enter their name and email address in order to receive a free report for download.

Do you know of an app which will let me store captured information in a database, and present the download link to them after registering?

I guess this can all be accomplished using a contact form script with database integration and jquery confirmation message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this contact form](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/03/12/php-mysql-contact-form-with-jquery/) which saves data into a database, and provides a jquery submission response which can include the download link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set it up with less programming effort just give Squeeze page plugins for Wordpress a try. There are lot's of them out there, see this discussion in the [Warriorforum](http://www.warriorforum.com/website-design/590956-best-wordpress-squeeze-page-plugin.html), or this commercial [offer](http://squeezepress.org/) or the general background on Squeeze pages on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_page). Take especially a look at [premise](http://getpremise.com/).

Comment: He didn't mention Wordpress at all.

Comment: This is why I wrote "...set it up with less programming effort...". I assumed what he really wants is a more complete thing ("Do you know of an app [...]"). I can be wrong that's ok.